# How to optimize a query based on another aggregation query

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table:

```
create table transfers(
ts timestamp without time zone,
departure varchar(3),
destination varchar(3),
price numeric
);
```

containing:

```
ts                      departure  destination  price
______________________________________________________
2020-11-01T15:00:00Z    Chicago     Berlin      500
2020-11-01T12:00:05Z    Chicago     Berlin      400
2020-11-01T20:01:00Z    Chicago     Berlin      920
2020-11-01T20:01:00Z    London      Berlin      800
2020-11-01T22:00:00Z    London      Berlin      750
```

I need to get prices for each departure point with the highest timestamp so the result should be:

```
ts                      departure  destination  price
______________________________________________________
2020-11-01T20:01:00Z    Chicago     Berlin      920
2020-11-01T22:00:00Z    London      Berlin      750
```

I did it using query:

```
with max_ts_per_departure AS (
        SELECT MAX(ts) AS ts, departure
        FROM transfers
        GROUP BY departure
)
        SELECT t.ts, mtpd.departure, t.price
        FROM max_ts_per_departure AS mtpd
        INNER JOIN transfers AS t
        ON mtpd.departure=t.departure AND mtpd.ts=t.ts;
```

Is there a way to shorten the query and avoid using WITH statement without slowing the execution time too much? Real data is much larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (departure) *
FROM transfers
ORDER BY departure, ts DESC;
```

Comment: This returns:
'departure  price  max_ts
Chicago          400  2020-11-01T12:00:05Z
Chicago          500  2020-11-01T15:00:00Z
Chicago          920  2020-11-01T20:01:00Z
London          750  2020-11-01T22:00:00Z
London          800  2020-11-01T20:01:00Z'

Not the expected result.

Comment: Try the updated answer.

Comment: This works. For full db execution time becomes slow but I solved this using an additional index.  `CREATE INDEX idx_max_ts ON transfers (ts DESC NULLS LAST, departure);`  Thanks.